# PHP SQL Array repeating every single ID in foreach loop instead of one ID at a time

Tags: php, sql, database, foreach

I am trying to make a script where I can surface with my database but I realized some special characters are being problematic as they're supposed to run a SQL

```
$sql = Db::getInstance()->executeS('SELECT `id_product` FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'product WHERE reference = '.$ref.';');
```

But some of $ref variables (it's a loop) have strange characters such as - or white space that would normally require me, in a query, to use ' ' or " ". How can I fix this in PHP?

Comment: If you remove the WHERE clause, then your query _will_ return all rows in that table, of course. Is your `$ref` variable correct?

Comment: A casual reading looks like the sql as written should do what you want: the where clause is absolutely necessary. What I don’t see is how your results are coming from this code.

Comment: @droopsnoot I edited in the output from when I echo what's in the $ref variable

Comment: @TimMorton Could it be a matter of syntax? I tried to replicate some of those queries that are false (which in reality are true) and they came off wrong because they lacked '' but I am not really lucid on how I can implement that without having the PHP code treat the variable as text

Comment: That’s because you should be using prepared statements (where ? is substituted for the field value).  Since the object uses a method named `execute`, it probably has a `prepare()` method for preparing the query. The where clause would look like `WHERE reference =?`. Check the docs for how your object does this; I don’t know how this one does it.